# NoMethodError: undefined method `hours' for "1":String

Tags: ruby, time, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am getting this error all the time

```
#<NoMethodError: undefined method `hours' for "1":String>
```

UPDATE: I am getting errors for any number not just "1"

and here is the code that I am returning hours. i am using this method

```
def check_hours(most_recent_snooze)
    if most_recent_snooze.duration.nil?
      return 0.hours
    else
      return most_recent_snooze.duration.hours
    end
  end
```

and these code uses check_hours(most_recent_snooze) method

```
def snoozing?
    if most_recent_snooze = Snooze.find_by_sensor_id(self.id)
      if most_recent_snooze && !(most_recent_snooze.created_at + check_hours(most_recent_snooze) < Time.now)
        # snooze is active
        return true
      else
        most_recent_snooze.destroy
        return false
      end
    end
    return false
    #self.snoozes.active.present? ? true : false
  end

  def snooze_minutes_remaining
    # (60 - (Time.now - self.snoozes.last.created_at)/60).to_i + 1
    most_recent_snooze = Snooze.find_by_sensor_id(self.id)
    distance_of_time_in_words(Time.now, most_recent_snooze.created_at + check_hours(most_recent_snooze)) if most_recent_snooze
  end
```

Please let me know on where did I go wrong on this code?

UPDATE:
Inside schema.rb, duration is integer

create_table "snoozes", :force => true do |t|
    .......
    ........
    .........
    **t.integer  "duration"**
  end

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ActiveSupport's time methods can be applied to Fixnums only, and it seems that some data you are passing in is a string. Perhaps you have a database column in an incorrect format?

A good way to handle this is to use an explicit `to_i` conversion in your method:

```
def check_hours(most_recent_snooze)
  most_recent_snooze.duration.to_i.hours
end
```

`nil.to_i` returns `0`, so you don't need the nil check in this case.

Comment: please see my edit, duration is integer, do I still need to convert to integer?

Comment: I usually do in these cases, even if I expect all of the data coming in to be integers. Calling `to_i` on an integer doesn't harm it in any way, plus it gets rid of your edge cases like `nil` and the string issue you've already run into. Another benefit is it makes your code somewhat self-documenting.

Answer (score 0):

Your most_recent_snooze's duration, for some reason is a string. If you can't fix that, try this in `check_hours`:

```
def check_hours(most_recent_snooze)
  if most_recent_snooze.duration.nil?
    return 0.hours
  else
    return most_recent_snooze.duration.to_i.hours
  end
end
```

Comment: This is a really odd way of doing this. `nil.to_i` is `0`, so there's no reason for testing against `nil?`.

Comment: please see my edit, duration is integer, do I still need to convert to integer?

Comment: @JitenK: Acording to your error message, it isn't: "undefined method `hours' for "1": *String*"

Comment: @Linuxious: Just checked the data type inside postgres of 'duration' is integer

Comment: @JitenK: Than it's being transformed somewhere. The point is, by the time you call it, it's a string wheather you like it or not.